# Is every isometric relation derivable and constructible (from/to some set of points) via rigid transformations? Can these be expressed exhaustively?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, notation, projective-geometry, isometry

There are three types of rigid transformations that can be combined to create an isometry: reflection, translation, rotation. The former two can be applied to any function to create a new (or trivially, identical) function in isometric correspondence,  whereas the latter cannot in general (only to bijections) although can be applied to non-invertible relations.  Can these be expressed as a mapping $f$? Let $\{f\}$ denote the set of all mappings $f$ from one set-relation to all its isometries, where $c$ and $d$ represent fixed constants (causing a translation) and a negative sign ($-$ from $±$) before one or more of the variables represents a reflection.

$\stackrel{A}{\{(x,\:y)\}_1}\quad\stackrel{\{f\}}{\mapsto}\quad\big\{\{(±x+c,\:±y+d)\}_{\{≅A_1\}}\big\}$

Does this look right (for two variables, without rotation)?  If so, does it extend without issues to more dimensions?, and How can rotations be applied (without, and if possible also with, precluding multiple-to-one mappings with or without restrictions)?

Comment: You might be happier approaching this from the framing of [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates).

Comment: Your set of mappings, $\{f\}$ doesn't seem to do what you write that it does (when it labels the arrow in your display).  The set of translations applied to a point is the entire enclosing space, not specific points, so the image of the map would seem to be $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @Eric Towers  ~~Does [homogeneous-spaces] tag seem fitting?$\quad$  Would you mind elaborating upon why {*f*} doesn't do what is indicated (including its relation to ℝ^2)?

Comment: [homogeneous-spaces] tag: not really -- you're not in the setting of Lie groups.  $\{f\}$ contains all translations.  When you apply all translations to a point you obtain all points in $\Bbb{R}^2$, not a collection of sets of points.